# Azure AD returns claims in a different format than expected

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am encountering an issue where Azure AD is returning claims in a format that is unexpected. I think the difference is between version 1 and version 2 of the claims object getting returned. I have looked through the Azure portal for an app setting that deals with this and done various Innerwebs searches but can't find an answer regarding how to return a particular version instead of another.

I am expecting to get back claims formatted similar to this :

```
  "AuthenticationType": "Cookies",
  "IsAuthenticated": true,
  "Actor": null,
  "BootstrapContext": null,
  "Claims": [
    {
      "Issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/v2.0",
      "OriginalIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/v2.0",
      "Properties": {},
      "Type": "aud",
      "Value": "yyy",
      "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    } 
    ... etc.
```

What I am getting is this :

```
{
  "System.Security.ClaimsIdentity.version": "1.0",
  "System.Security.ClaimsIdentity.nameClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
  "System.Security.ClaimsIdentity.roleClaimType": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid",
  "System.Security.ClaimsIdentity.claims": "Encrypted value here",
  "m_userToken": {
    "value": 0
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> how to return a particular version instead of another.

You may have to  change the accessTokenAcceptedVersion part of the `manifest to 2` if you want a **V2** access token.  If its value is null or 1, that  means your app will only accept the v1 token.

[image]

But please note that scopes for microsoft graph api , always returns version 1 tokens.

> For example `User.Read` is an access token for MS Graph and those are
> always V1 access tokens. That means the token is for the Microsoft
> Graph, not for your particular API. To get a token for your backend API,
> try to invoke
> acquireTokenSilent and  pass the scopes for that API.

The v2 authorization endpoint is
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` and
v2 token endpoint is   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token`

wheere as the v1 authorization endpoint is like:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/authorize?`
and v1 token endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/token`

**References:**

1. [how-to-get-access-token-version-2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/639834/how-to-get-access-token-version-20.html)
2. [V1 and V2 Identity and Access tokens with Azure Active Directory](https://matthijs.hoekstraonline.net/2020/04/27/v1-and-v2-identity-and-access-tokens-with-azure-active-directory/)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a data integrity issue. Our customer's Azure AD client id was entered with a trailing space. The neither the web app nor Azure trims the string. Once the trailing space was removed everything works as expected.